# Redirecting from IP Address to another with keeping other parts of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I need help with `.htaccess`. I'm using apache.

I want to change my server IP to another one.

Example:

```
http://127.0.0.1/files/image.png
```

to

```
http://192.196.1.1/files/image.png
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Comment: I'm not using htaccess file at this moment.

Comment: This is evidently an _internal_ IP address, why do you need to issue an external redirect? Or do you simply want to "change [your] server IP" (no redirect)? However, something like this really shouldn't be done in `.htaccess` (as tagged), since the website itself shouldn't be accessible from both IPs (if it is then you aren't actually _changing_ anything). (?)

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 127\.0\.0\.1 
RewriteRule ^ http://192.196.1.1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```